# How to copy methods from instance of some class to object

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance

Given class

```
class Test {
  test() {
     console.log('test called');
  }
}
```

And some object `toExtend = {}`

How can I extend this object so it will have `test` method?

`Object.assign` ( as well as `_.extend`, `_.assign`, `$.extend`) do not copy methods. What is preferable way to do that?

Note that `toExtend` is passed from outside

UPD:
`toExtend` is instance of another class and has it's own prototype's methods

Comment: You have to deal with object's prototype: `toExtend.prototype...`

Comment: @hindmost turns out you don't anymore! (at least not directly, they improved it)

Comment: @hindmost `toExtend` does not have a `prototype` property since it is not a function. I think you mean `__proto__`.

Answer (score 9):

### Object Literals

For object literals, which start with no protoype of their own (`Object.getPrototypeOf(toExtend) === Object.protoype)`), you can simply use [`Object.setPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf) to extend the object:

```js
class Test {
  test() {
    console.log('test called');
  }
}

const toExtend = {};

// Set the prototype, so you "inherit" methods:
Object.setPrototypeOf(toExtend, Test.prototype);
toExtend.test();
```

In older runtimes, you would have to manually assign the prototype:

```js
function Test() {
  // noop ctor
}

Test.prototype.test = function() {
  console.log('test called');
};


var toExtend = {};

// Set the prototype, so you "inherit" methods:
toExtend.__proto__ = Test.prototype;
toExtend.test();
```

### Class Instances

For instances of an existing class, things are significantly more complex. They do have a prototype of their own, potentially with properties that must be copied, so you need to walk through those:

```js
class Foo {
  test() {
    console.log('test');
  }
}

class Bar {
  toast() {
    console.log('toast');
  }
}

function dynamicExtend(target, base) {
  const baseProto = Object.getPrototypeOf(target);
  if (baseProto == Object.prototype) {
    // simple case: no existing prototype
    Object.setPrototypeOf(target, base.prototype);
  } else {
    // complex case: existing prototype
    const proxyClass = class extends base {};
    const proxyProto = proxyClass.prototype;

    // assign the target properties
    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(baseProto).forEach(n => {
      const desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(baseProto, n);
      Object.defineProperty(proxyProto, n, desc);
    });

    Object.setPrototypeOf(target, proxyProto);
  }
}

const targets = [{},
  new Bar()
];

targets.forEach(t => {
  dynamicExtend(t, Foo);
  t.test();
  if (t.toast) {
    t.toast();
  }
});
```

Note that, thanks to the proxy class, this does break `instanceof` style inheritance checks.

### `__proto__`

As @PatrickRoberts [noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37886299/how-to-copy-methods-from-instance-of-some-class-to-object/37886365?noredirect=1#comment63227749_37886365) in the comments, [`__proto__` is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto), so you should prefer `setPrototypeOf` whenever possible.

Comment: It should be noted that [`__proto__` is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto) and heavily advised against if you want to ensure support. It's better to get direct access to `toExtend`'s constructor (`ToExtend`) and use `ToExtend.prototype = new Test();` before adding methods to `ToExtend.prototype`.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts except `toExtend` doesn't have a constructor of its own in this case. We're adding a prototype to a plain old JS object, so `toExtend.constructor === Object`, which we most certainly cannot extend.

Comment: I know, but I meant in general, whenever possible, it is better to edit the constructor directly.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts For sure. I added a note in the answer to make that clear.

Comment: @ssube but what if toExtend has it's own prototype and methods?

Comment: @IharKrasnik in your example (`toExtend = {}`), `toExtend` will not have a prototype or methods, thanks to being an object literal. If `toExtend` is an instance of some other class, you need to dynamically create a fake class and set up inheritance. I'm working on a way to handle both cases.

Comment: @IharKrasnik I've come up with something that appears to work in my test cases. I'm not sure how robust it is across the board, but take a look and let me know if it helps you! :)